# Почему in_array() срабатывает 1 раз?

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Почему срабатывает 1 раз? Выводит 1, а потом всё время 2. Хотя `in_array()` содержит все поля, которые проверяет.

```
$objidd = mysql_query("SELECT `internal-id` FROM object1");
$objarr=  mysql_fetch_array($objidd);

$usertr = mysql_query("SELECT idzk FROM allurlszhhk");

while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($usertr)){       
     $xml = simplexml_load_file("xmlfiles/".$row['idzk'].".xml"); 

     foreach ($xml->offer as $offer){   
         $id = 'internal-id';
         $idint = $offer[$id];        

         var_dump( $idint, $objarr );

         if ( in_array( $idint, $objarr ) ) {
              echo 'Сработало первое выражение'; 
         }
         else{
              echo 'Сработал false выражение';     
         }
      }
}
```

Вывод скрипта:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
}
array(2) { 
   [0]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
   ["internal-id"]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
}
Сработало первое выражение!
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
    [0]=> string(8) "f7989546" 
}
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
    ["internal-id"]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
}
Сработал false выражение!
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
    [0]=> string(8) "f7989547" 
}
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
    ["internal-id"]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
} 
Сработал false выражение!
object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (1) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "f7989548" 
} 
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
   ["internal-id"]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
} 
Сработал false выражение!
object(SimpleXMLElement)#48 (1) {
    [0]=> string(8) "f7989549" 
} 
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(8) "f7989545"
    ["internal-id"]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
} 
Сработал false и тд */
```

Comment: В блоке где выводит 2 сделайте var_dump для $idint и $objarr и убедитесь, что действительно содержит ...

Comment: Зачем проверяете var_dump вместо самого in_array?

Comment: Без var_dump тоже не срабатывает!!!

Comment: Так? if(in_array($idint, $objarr)){
            echo '1';
        }
        else{           
         echo   var_dump($idint);  echo   var_dump($objarr); 
        }

Comment: что такое `$id`?

Comment: @Нетглупыхвопросов Добавил в свой ответ код для проверки.

Comment: object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { [0]=> string(8) "f7989546" } array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "f7989545" ["internal-id"]=> string(8) "f7989545" } object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) { [0]=> string(8)

Comment: Я же сказал, что без var_dump тоже не работает!!!!!

Comment: Может я что-то не понимаю, но какой смысл проверять var_dump у objarr он естественно покажет первую ячейку, разве нет?

Comment: А что такое $idint и где он выставляется?

Comment: В процессе правки потерялся. Восстановил.

Comment: Так из вывода у вас idint = f7989546 а после первого - у вас в массиве f7989545. Всё верно, что не так то ?

Comment: Так я и говорил выше, что var_dump не дают полную выборку , а  idint показывает первую ячейку массива.in array() должен находить содержимое ячейки в  idint

Comment: нет, вардамп выводит всё что есть. Значит в массиве у вас одна ячейка. Не пытайтесь вардамп заставить работать за вас :-)\

Comment: вы попробуйте `in_array((string) $idint, $objarr)`; вернее не попробуйте, а сделайте.

Comment: @teran а смысл, это php он сам приводит типы

Comment: Хм, действительно одна :( Спасибо Чад!

Comment: @Чад, да, что-то невнимательно дамп посмотрел. Приводит то приводит, но для получения значений узлов simpleXml необходимо привести к строке. и `echo $node` выведет `object` а не значение узла, в то время как `echo (string)$node` получит значение. Но тут это не к месту, да.

Comment: Теран, а есть мануал по редактированию вопросов. мне всегда неудобно, что за меня правят постоянно, что бы хоть как-то читалось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Суть вашей проблемы что вы вы выдёргиваете в

`$objarr=mysql_fetch_array($objidd);` одну строчку из `object1` где колонки в виде массива, а не всю таблицу в массив как ожидаете.

Comment: Если есть какие мысли почему выборку делает из одной строки: $objidd = mysql_query("SELECT `internal-id` FROM object1"); // internal-id в косых кавычках

Comment: @Нетглупыхвопросов потому что fetch извлекает только одну строку из результата, вам же нужно извлечь все и сложить в массив, а потом работать с ними.

Comment: Спасибо, Теран!

Comment: Я думал, что in_array() находит данные из всего ассоциативного массива. (

Answer (score 3):

Вы проверяете `var_dump` вместо самого `in_array`:

```
if(var_dump(in_array($idint, $objarr))){
```

Но `var_dump` сам по себе [ничего не возвращает](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php#refsect1-function.var-dump-returnvalues), поэтому `if` видит `NULL` и идёт к `else`.

Замените код и проверьте, что на самом деле получает `in_array`:

```
    var_dump( $idint, $objarr );
    if ( in_array( $idint, $objarr ) ) {
        echo '1';
    }
    else{
        echo '2';
    }
```

---

**UPD**. Судя по добавленному вами дампу, вывод соответствует данным.

1. в обоих переменных лежат массивы;
2. в первом сравнении `in_array` находит `[0]=> string(8) "f7989545"` внутри массива

```
array(2) {  
   [0]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
   ["internal-id"]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
}
```

а во всех последующих не находит, потому что искомых элементов в них действительно нет. Например, `[0]=> string(8) "f7989546"` нет в массиве

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
    ["internal-id"]=> string(8) "f7989545" 
}
```

и так далее.

Comment: Не работает я же написал выше!

Comment: Код в ответе должен вывести информацию об `$idint` и `$ojarr`. Добавьте то, что он вывел, в текст вопроса, чтобы в этой информации было легче разобраться.

Comment: Поправил текст вопроса.

Comment: Почему in_array срабатывает один раз?

Comment: Дамп показывает, что `in_array` находит искомые данные только в первом случае. Дополнил ответ.